# error in scraping inner tags of html element using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, data-science

Recently i am working on exercise and in which i had extracted whole webpage source data . I am very much interested in area tag . In area tag i am very much interested in onclick attribute . Now how can we extract onclick attribute from particular element .
Now our extracted data is looking like these ,

```
<area class="borderimage" coords="21.32,14.4,933.96,180.56" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return show_pop('78545','51022929357','1')" onmouseover="borderit(this,'black','<b>इंदौर, गुरुवार, 10 मई , 2018  <b><br><bआप पढ़ रहे हैं देश का सबसे व...')" onmouseout="borderit(this,'white')" alt="<b>इंदौर, गुरुवार, 10 मई , 2018  <b><br><bआप पढ़ रहे हैं देश का सबसे व..." shape="rect">
```

I am very much interested in onclick attribute and my code is like these which i had already done but nothing has worked ,

```
paper_url  = 'http://epaper.bhaskar.com/indore/129/10052018/mpcg/1/'
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}

    # Total number of pages available in these product
    page = requests.get(paper_url,headers = headers)
    page_response = page.text
    parser = html.fromstring(page_response)
    XPATH_Total_Pages = '//div[contains(@class,"fs12 fta w100 co_wh pdt5")]//text()'
    raw_total_pages = parser.xpath(XPATH_Total_Pages)
    lastpage=raw_total_pages[-1]
    print(int(lastpage))
    finallastpage=int(lastpage)
    reviews_list = []
    XPATH_PRODUCT_NAME = '//map[contains(@name,"Mapl")]'

    #XPATH_PRODUCT_PRICE  = '//span[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]/text()'

    #raw_product_price = parser.xpath(XPATH_PRODUCT_PRICE)
    #product_price = raw_product_price
    raw_product_name = parser.xpath(XPATH_PRODUCT_NAME)

    XPATH_REVIEW_SECTION_2 = '//area[@class="borderimage"]'
    reviews = parser.xpath(XPATH_REVIEW_SECTION_2)

    product_name =raw_product_name
    #result = product_name.find(',')
    #finalproductname = slice[0:product_name]
    print(product_name)
    print(reviews)

    for review in reviews:
        #soup = BeautifulSoup(str(review), "html.parser")
        #parser2.feed(str(review))
        #allattr = [tag.attrs for tag in review.findAll('onclick')]
        #print(allattr)

        XPATH_RATING  = './/area[@data-hook="onclick"]'

        raw_review_rating = review.xpath(XPATH_RATING)
        #cleaning data
        print(raw_review_rating)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right - you need to get all `onclick` attributes of `<area>` tags on a page.

Try something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

TAG_NAME = 'area'
ATTR_NAME = 'onclick'

url = 'http://epaper.bhaskar.com/indore/129/10052018/mpcg/1/'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

# there are 3 <area> tags on page; putting them into a list
area_onclick_attrs = [x[ATTR_NAME] for x in soup.findAll(TAG_NAME)]
print(area_onclick_attrs)
```

Output:

```
[
    "return show_pophead('78545','51022929357','1')", 
    "return show_pop('78545','51022928950','4')", 
    "return show_pop('78545','51022929357','1')",
]
```